# Flutter Class level variable bool not working

Tags: android, dart, flutter

The below snipet always printing debugging enabled whether debug is 0 or 1
  Even if we take debug as bool and checking true or false same thing happens
  what is the problem is syntax wrong or fields below works always in other 
  languages like java, kotlin, kotlin-native and others i tried them

```
  int debug = 1;

  checkDebug(int i) {
    //int debug = 1;
    Color color;
    if (debug == 1) {
      print('debugging enabled');
      switch (i) {
        case 1:
          color = Colors.amber;
          break;
        case 2:
          color = Colors.amberAccent;
          break;
        case 3:
          color = Colors.blue;
          break;
        case 4:
          color = Colors.black;
          break;
        default:
      }
      return color;
    } else if (debug == 0) {
      print('debugging disabled');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

What is the possible solution for this since i always have debug variable on top of class with other variables this code works only when debug is assigned in method only

Edit: Answer

Above uses Stateful widget so when changing variables call setState() solves the issue

```
void changeVariable(){
  debug = 0;
  setState((){});
}
```

solves the issue

Comment: where you pass the variable debug? is that inside a button click event or somewhere ele?

Comment: Do you have relative imports in `lib/main.dart` (imports that don't start with `import 'package:...`) or do you import `lib/main.dart` from any other file?

Comment: If you use anything like this you want to change the bool val inside setState() method

Comment: Can you put your full class so that it will be easy to help.

Comment: Yes are right @ArchuMohan  i was using stateful widget such a silly mistake i have done is not using setState((){}); thanks for your suggestion already changed code anyway thanks, Answer to the above code is i had made a seperate method to change variable and calling setState() solves the issue.

Comment: Good Happy coding ;)